# The Woo-Commerce Location and Address in the Database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently adding a WordPress function where we get the addresses and display them in a list. The issue is I can't find the product address, does anyone know where this would be?

Comment: What addresses? And what is the 'product address'?

Comment: Can you provide more info and some code?